# What are some common UX Design and Problem solving frameworks/checklists?

Tags: methodology, ux-methods

Are there any standard checklists or frameworks for UX Problem Solving?

EDIT:  *I realize there's no one-size fits all, but looking for a starting point. Might not do all of the steps, but might prevent missing a step.*

In Technical troubleshooting there is the standard TroubleShooting method I learned in the military, similar to the Scientific Method

1. Identify the Symptom
2. Confirm/Reproduce the Symptom
3. Identify possible Causes (in software this would be breaking the program down into pieces/components)
4. Test each possible cause to rule it out
5. Once we confirm the component that is causing the problem, try to break it down further.
6. Fix problem
7. confirm fix by repeating Step 2.
8. Document solution if it's likely to occur again.

Answer (score 2):

UX is not a process, there isn't a manual. Sometimes you need to understand the business needs, other times you need to discover the user needs.

> Do not repeat the tactics which have gained you one victory, but let your methods be regulated by the infinite variety of circumstances.
> -- Sun Tzu

But if you want some framework, you must read Jaime's book UX Strategy. In this book you will discover methods and how to apply them. Another book, Tim Brown's book Design Thinking, you will discover a Design Thinking process.

Comment: Do you mean this Tim Brown book:  Change by Design...

 https://smile.amazon.com/Change-Design-Revised-Updated-Organizations/dp/0062856626/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=Design+Thinking+by+Tim+Brown&qid=1607570150&sr=8-1

Comment: That is a really good answer!

Comment: "Understand Business Needs" would be one of the items in the check list. 
If there aren't business needs, then you'd just skip that item.

Comment: Depends 
Sometimes the stakeholders can be in love for one solution, and you need to understand if the users want this solution, if real pain.

Every project the business has a interest and need, for the both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there is no one set process that one can use every time. However, I do think that there are a couple of broad universal principles that could be applied regardless of the type of challenge presented. Those are based on the Design Thinking process. For example, some of the core ones would be:

- Know your user.
- Start with a problem.
- Identify the need to diverge or converge in thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to look at Polya's problem solving method "How to Solve it"

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)

> How to Solve It suggests the following steps when solving a mathematical problem:
>
> 1. First, you have to understand the problem.
> 2. After understanding, make a plan.
> 3. Carry out the plan.
> 4. Look back on your work.How could it be better?
>    If this technique fails, Pólya advises: "If you can't solve a problem,
>    then there is an easier problem you can solve: find it." Or: "If you
>    cannot solve the proposed problem, try to solve first some related
>    problem. Could you imagine a more accessible related problem?"

It then dives deeper into each step, I'd suggest you to take a look